# How to add prefix to cookie in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, setcookie

I have run a scan on SecurityHeaders.com which shows a warning that cookie has no prefix and I don't know how to add a prefix to a cookie. Can anybody tell me how to do it in asp.net core ?. [Screenshot of website scan result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od319.png)

Here is the ConfigureServices method from Startup.cs class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
               .AddAzureAdB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options))
               .AddCookie(); 

            services.AddMvc()
               .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession();
       }
```

And here is Configure method

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            }
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute("home", "{action=Index}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home" });
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

Comment: How are you setting the cookie?

Comment: I'm configuring it from configureservices method  in startup class using cookiepolicyoptions and then adding usecookiepolicy in configure method.

Comment: Please include that code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. So posting it here if anybody needs it.
Within the SessionOptions, set Cookie.Name to prefix+name.

Below **__Secure-** is prefix in Session Cookie Name.

```
services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "__Secure-.AspNetCore.Session";
                //options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600);
                //options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
```

and yes it solves the security header issue in scan too.